# Condition in the error: 'mysql has gone away'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a server and it performs actions every 10 seconds, but sometimes, it returns the error 'mysql has gone away'.
I wonder when this error is returned for the page to be refreshed.
I tried the following way but it did not work:

```
$remote_db = mysql_pconnect($remote_db_host, $remote_db_user, $remote_db_pass) or die (mysql_error());
    if(!$remote_db) {
    //error on connect
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">';
    }
    mysql_select_db($remote_db_name, $remote_db) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: using `mysql_*` is bad enough as it is, already, but using `mysql_pconnect` is terrible, a crime against humanity. I'd have to take it personal, if you keep this up

Answer (score 0):

That's a timeout message. Your PHP code took too long to do anything with the MySQL server and therefore it went away.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the persistent connection you are using have died.

So, stop using `mysql_pconnect` and switch to `mysql_connect`.

For most cases it is actually speedier to do a normal connect than to try to use a persistant connection.

(And as a side-note: you should really take a look at PDO. `mysql_` usage is strongly discouraged.)

Comment: `mysql_*` isn't discouraged, it's _deprecated_. Usage of `mysql_*` has been discouraged for years, since PHP5.5, `mysql_*` functions actually raise `E_DEPRECATED` warnings, so advising OP to switch to `mysql_connect` is like advising someone to look away, because his house is on fire... change it or be down-voted